# My php routing doesn't work and getting 500 error code

Tags: php, apache, rest, ubuntu, routes

I have a PHP site and simple routing but the site doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting server internal error 500 code.

This is my htaccess file [htaccess file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAIoB.png)

This is my index.php [index.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KObwy.png)

This is my site.conf file for apache2 [site.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3oDD.png)

The website works fine with PHPStorm built-in web server. but it doesn't work when it is uploaded to the server. File permission seems to be okay.

Comment: Check the error logs, an error 500 is generic, there is a specific reason

Comment: ```error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/MedEx/vendor/composer/platform_check.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/MedEx/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 25```

This is the error I'm getting.

Comment: A general note: you should definitely maintain a development setup (the one buildin to the IDE is _not_ enough). That means a local LAMP stack that acts as a staging setup. Where you can run your tests in a real live environment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error message is quite plain: `autoload_real.php on line 25` is trying to `require` a non-existent `platform_check.php` file.

Comment: yep had some vendor files missiong